# Matching network problem in CMX902 power amplifier with SX1261

Tags: rf, schematics, impedance-matching, power-amplifier, lora

I'm trying to design a schematic of 3 Watt device using an SX1261 radio transceiver. For the power amplifier, I've chosen CMX902. I'm a little bit confused about the schematic I'm drawing, is it correct or not? Also, I need an explanation about the matching network provided by CMX902, which of them is the impedance matching stage, 2nd order filtering stage, or the higher-order filtering stage? If it is wrong then what modifications do I've to do to the schematic? I've followed both the reference application schematic provided in SX1261 and  CMX902 data sheets. All the reference images are given below

[image: My proposed schematic]
Fig1: My proposed schematic

[image: General matching network provided CMX902]
Fig2: General matching network provided CMX902

[image: Application design of the SX1261 with RF switch]
Fig3: Application design of the SX1261 with RF switch

Comment: At which frequency do you want to use it? You have output RFO shorted to GND in the first schematic.

Comment: @Jens wants to operate it on 433 MHz, Actually, the circuit is intentionally shorted.

Answer (score 1):

For C1,C2 the BOM calls up
[image]. The 47nF is X7R and the 47 pF is NP0/C0G for low ESR.

If you are unsure how to design every aspect, consider the Development Kit with firmware and GUI software.  The BOM (bill of material) included in the Zip File is based on assumptions for frequency.

[image]

[image]

[image]

https://www.semtech.com/products/wireless-rf/lora-core/sx1261dvk1bas#datasheets